# Unable to open the link in next tab or in another window using webdriver

Tags: selenium

In our application, we have a link called `forgot password?` and with `contextClick()` I am able to do right click on the link and but could not able to open the same link either in New tab or window.
Code which i used is as below.

```java
WebElement wbLink=d.findElement(By.xpath("My xpath here"));

Actions act=new Actions(d);
act.contextClick(wbLink).sendKeys("W").build().perform();

//act.contextClick(wbLink).sendKeys("T").build().perform();
```

And also tried below way as well.

```java
Actions act=new Actions(d);
act.contextClick(wbLink).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"T")).build().perform();
```

Any suggestions would be appreciate on this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `contextClick()`, you can open link in new tab using `sendKeys()` as below :-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

String keys = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN);

WebElement wbLink=d.findElement(By.xpath("My xpath here"));
wbLink.sendKeys(keys);
```

**Note** :- Use `Keys.COMMAND` instead of `Keys.CONTROL` if you are using `mac`